# Google Cloud Messaging developer android code crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to make an application with Google Cloud Messaging and i followd all the exact steps for implementing GCMclient on developer page, code just seems to crash on launch. Is there any fault in activity main? or some logical flaw of how android sets up its application on creation? im new to android programming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.iotproj.clandestine"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.iotproj.clandestine.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.iotproj.clandestine" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="GcmIntentService" />

  </application>


  </manifest>



          public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;TextView mDisplay;
Button mButton;

GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
Context appContext = getApplicationContext();

// this is quite important dude
String registrationId = null;


String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxx";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pool);
    mButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getid);

    // Check device for Play Services APK.
    if (!checkPlayServices()) {

        mDisplay.setText("device not supproted !");   button.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(appContext);
            try{
                registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);   
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                mDisplay.setText(e.getMessage());
            }               
        }
    });
}`
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing more details about the exception you get?

Comment: im running it on my phone so as soon as it is deployed it just says unfortunately application has stopped working. do you want me share mainactiviy.java ?

Comment: @br0k3nc0d3 Actually i was talking about the exception that must have been shown in LogCat. It should be written in red.

Answer (score 1):

Register your broadcast receiver like this way.

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.iotproj.clandestine" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

for Service

```
 <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: for android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" i have changed it to android:name="com.iotproj.clandestine".GCMBroadcastReceiver", still not working

Comment: my source directory structure is, i have a package for the app and all three files are in it only. GcmBroadcastReceiver, GcmIntentService and MainActivity all together

Comment: Okay. But there is no problem of that. you have to register your receiver as a com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver.